# clean and build failed in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-6.9

I create a project in Netbeans IDE 6.9
In a project I have an interface IBusinessLogic
In second project I created a class BusinessLogic which implements IBusinessLogic 
In third project I am creating an object of BusienssLogic and assigning this object to reference of IBusinessLogic. I am not getting any error while writing but when 
I Clean and Build this third project I get the exception that below:

```
incompatible types
found   : com.abc.businesslogic.BusinessLogic
required: com.abc.businesslogic.interfaces.IBusinessLogic
                com.abc.businesslogic.interfaces.IBusinessLogic logic = bl;
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
D:\ProjectsFeb12\Service\nbproject\build-impl.xml:531: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\ProjectsFeb12\Service\nbproject\build-impl.xml:261: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

As I know that I can assign an object of sub type in super type reference then this exception must be of IDE. How can i solve this?
I moved all my code to a new project too but didnot worked.

Code:

```
package com.abc.workerhandlers;

import com.abc.businesslogic.BusinessLogic;
import com.abc.businesslogic.interfaces.IBusinessLogic;

public class MQ2MQWorker1 {

    MQ2MQWorker1(){}

    public void init(){

                BusinessLogic bl = new BusinessLogic();
                IBusinessLogic logic = bl;  // This line is giving problem
    }
}
```

When I run the project it executes perfectly but the jar of the project is not created in the dist directory.

Comment: Can you post a piece of your code where the error is occuring?

Comment: Are you sure `com.abc.businesslogic.BusinessLogic` implements `com.abc.businesslogic.interfaces.IBusinessLogic`?

Comment: Are you sure they are loaded by the same classloader? If not you would see this error.

Comment: How can i identify that both are loaded by same classloader?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the correct class is in the classpath? Btw,
you should not write

```
 BusinessLogic bl = new BusinessLogic();
IBusinessLogic logic = bl;  // This line is giving problem
```

but instead just `IBUsinessLogic logic = new BusinessLogic();`